# Meteor Error: Missing required parameters on path The missing params are: ["_id"]. The params object passed in was: {}

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have this in my routes:

```
Router.map(function() {
...
    this.route('studentEdit', {
        path: '/student/:_id/edit',
        data: function() {
            return Students.findOne(this.params._id);
        },
    });

    this.route('studentDetail', {
        path: '/student/:_id',
        data: function() {
            return Students.findOne(this.params._id);
        }
    });

...

});
```

And I have this in my template using autoform:

```
    {{#autoForm collection="Students" id="studentEdit" doc=this type="update"}}
        {{> afQuickField name='name'}} 
        {{> afQuickField name='phone'}} 
        {{> afQuickField name='address' rows=6}} 
        {{> afQuickField name='remarks' rows=6}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light"><i class="material-icons">save</i></button>
    {{/autoForm}}
```

The edit page loads fine, with the prepopulated fields. And when I save, it does save, yet, it doesn't redirect to the detail page, and returns this error in console:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking '/students/update': Error: Missing required parameters on path "/student/:_id". The missing params are: ["_id"]. The params object passed in was: {}.
```

**UPDATE**
Routing to the detail page now works, yet the error still exist in the console. I must be missing something. This is what I've done to get it working for the time being:

```
var moveOnRouter = {
    onSuccess: function(formType, result) {
        Router.go('studentDetail', {_id: this.docId});
    }
}

AutoForm.addHooks('studentEdit', moveOnRouter);
```

Comment: Where your `router.go()` to take you to the detail route?

Comment: Where do I add the Router.go()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly `go` to the other route on submit from your form. But since your button is a `submit` you also need to prevent the default submit action.

With template events you'd do something like:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'submit .btn'(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    router.go('studentDetail',{ _id: this.docId });
  }
});
```

But since you're hooking autoform perhaps it's easier just to remove the `type="submit"` from your button definition.